# How to get required response from DRF

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have database which consists of configuration of application. Application can have various configuration keys and basically I don't have information about how much keys I have and name of keys are not known too. I need to have response as {key: value, }. But I have response {key_field: key, value_field: value}. What should I do basically in this case? Does using MongoDB instead of PostgreSQL or SQlite help me? Or any other ideas?

Model looks like:

```
class Service(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()
    version = models.IntegerField()

class ServiceKey(models.Model):
    service = models.ForeignKey(
        Service,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    service_key = models.TextField()
    service_value = models.TextField()
```

views:

```
@api_view(['GET', ])
def hello(request):
    name = request.query_params.get('service')
    try:
        service = Service.objects.get(name=name)
        service_key_instance = ServiceKey.objects.filter(service=service)
        serializer = KeySerializer(instance=service_key_instance, many=True)

        return Response(data=serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
    except:
        Response(data='record not found', status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Comment: I think you need to be a bit clearer with how you're sending the response. In this case it's probably useful to add your `urls.py` and (more importantly) your `views.py` (your view of the API)

Comment: Did you mean request?

Comment: Added. Urls consists of one url. I send request using curl  with query parameter - service

Comment: In KeySerializer you can change the name of a model property, so the json doesn't need to match exactly the model. I often do it in `to_representation` method.

Answer (score 0):

on your serializer, you should  overwrite to_representation method for example:

```
class ServiceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Ticket
        fields = [
            "name",
            "version",
        ]

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        response = super().to_representation(instance)
        response["keys"] = {
        key.service_key: key.service_value for key in instance.service_key_set.all()
        }
        return response
```

and just use this serializer in your API view